# Custom rest API route not passing data along

Tags: rest-api

Trying to implement a simple API endpoint on a Wordpress site. I cannot seem to get the end of the URL to pass in to the callback...

```
function fc_category($request) {
    return func_get_args();
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 
        'freshstore', 
        '/category/(?P<id>.*+)', 
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'fc_category',
        ) 
    );
});
```

The return is an empty array:

```
[{}]
```

Tested my regex, it should be solid but... this is the first time I've tried to implement a Wordpress endpoint like this, so perhaps I am way off-base with how this works.

Comment: I see that `$request` is not being used here, how are you retrieving the ID? I would also version your route in case it changes in future, e.g. `'freshstore/v1'`

Answer (score 0):

So the value is hidden away in the array passed in to the callback. Accessed via the named capture group:

```
$request['id']
```